# Stacked horizontal bar chart: How to get the width of a bar?

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, chart.js, stacked-chart

How could I get the width of a bar/box like in this snippet:
http://jsfiddle.net/zk9oc4c9/
to determine the y-postions of the bar?

In the Fiddle above version 1.x is used but `this.chart.ctx.moveTo(0, this.scale.calculateY(lineHeight));` isn't possible in version 2.x.

With such kind of coordinates I want to draw a line into the chart. Drawing with static values (dummy data) works, but I need id dynamically.
So please see the screenshot how the chart looks like with static values for the line(s). The y-coordinates for the dashed line is easy - just the border of the chart. **But I mean the red solid line.**

[image]

So I wrote a plugin and this is the part where to draw the line(s) - this is just an excerpt:

```
Chart.plugins.register({
    afterDatasetsDraw: function(chartInstance, easing) {
        var coord = {
            x: // this calculation is already done,
            startY: 0,
            endY: 0
        };

        // actually draw the line
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(coord.x, coord.startY);
        ctx.lineTo(coord.x, coord.endY);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
});
```

**Edit**
I did some kind of solution. It's a bit a workaround, but it works:

```
Chart.plugins.register({
    afterDatasetsDraw: function(chartInstance, easing) {
        // get the meta from any dataset
        var meta = chartInstance.getDatasetMeta(0);
        var xScale = chartInstance.scales[meta.xAxisID];

        var coord = {
            x: xScale.getPixelForValue(<value for the line>);
            startY: 0,
            endY: 0
        };

        var yScale = chartInstance.scales[meta.yAxisID];
        // get the height of the y-axis  - subtract the top padding for the chart here
        var height = yScale.bottom - yScale.top;
        // get categoryPercentage & barPercentage from the chart's configuration
        var catPerc = yScale.options.categoryPercentage;
        var barPerc = yScale.options.barPercentage;

        // calculate the each category height
        var catHeight = (height * catPerc) / yScale.ticks.length;
        // so calculate the height of a single bar
        var barHeight = catHeight * barPerc;

        var factor = barHeight / catHeight;

        // padding between chat edge and the bar itself
        var padding = (catHeight - barHeight) * factor;
        // use the top value from which the chart itself is rendered + the padding
        coord.startY = yScale.top + padding - 2;
        coord.endY = coord.startY + barHeight + 3;

        // actually draw the line
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(coord.x, coord.startY);
        ctx.lineTo(coord.x, coord.endY);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
});
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking can you elaborate

Comment: Do you mean something like this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7oo4ugbj/

Comment: Sorry for being not precise enough. I edited the text